# Spring Boot HttpSecurity fluent api order?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

*Spring 2.0.3.RELEASE*

Goal: Implement Spring Boot Security (basic auth for starters) on all endpoints except `/actuator/health`, `/actuator/info` and `/ping` (a custom controller that just returns `ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build()`).

The below gives me a `401`. Any combination seems to either give me complete anonymous access to all endpoints or `401` to all.

I've set the `spring.security.user.name` and `...password` in `application.yml` and it is working correctly.

I've implemented...

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        super.configure(http);

        // just trying to get health working for starters
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().permitAll();
    }
}
```

The below seemed like it was restricted to Actuator's `/health` and `/info` endpoints, but instead is also opening up my custom `/ping` endpoint as well (it's not in this list).

```
http.requestMatcher(EndpointRequest.to("health", "info"))
    .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
```

Comment: Did you try with 
@Order(ManagementServerProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)?

Comment: I did, but it wasn't necessary in the end

Comment: @YogenRai, that field has been removed in Spring Boot 2. The 1.x version had it: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/ManagementServerProperties.html, but the 2.x version does not: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/web/server/ManagementServerProperties.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being a bug in Spring Tool Suite. Using `Boot Dashboard` with a Gradle project wasn't always picking up build output. It seems to be using a different directory and I cannot figure it out.

The HttpSecurity configuration that ended up working for me was:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http.
        authorizeRequests().
            antMatchers("/ping", "/actuator/health", "/actuator/info", "/login").permitAll().
            anyRequest().authenticated().and().
        httpBasic().and().
        // CSRF tokens for API access
        csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
    // @formatter:on
}
```